# An Open Source No Root good firewall?

Tags: android, open-source, firewall

Do you know any open source android firewall which work whithout needing to be root? I found some, but they just let me permit or deny access to internet for each app. I need a fire wall on which I can make rules about IPs,ports, or something like these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Netguard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.netguard) may be what you're looking for.

1) No root

2) 100% open source

3) Allow/block individual addresses per application (Paid only)

4) Also PCAP logging like Wireshark.

> There is no other no-root firewall offering all these features.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.netguard

Comment: Is there any other that you know of? I'm looking for the smallest example that I can try. Also with a more permissive license.